# Curious about different ways of swearing in Mandarin

Tags: mandarin, traditional-characters, learning, spoken, swearing

I'm not sure if this is considered an appropriate conversation or question but I've had conversations with Cantonese speakers before who've mentioned that it's so easy to swear in Cantonese, but there aren't a lot of ways to do that in Mandarin. I was wondering if anyone knew of any resources I could use on different ways of swearing in Mandarin?

Comment: You have tons of ways to swear, in any human language.

Comment: Just imagine something offensive and put it in spoken words. For example 川X是吃X拉飯, 祇得三歲智商的白痴謊話王,

Comment: search web using 咒骂大全:  http://zaojv.com/3320146_2.html

Comment: Did you mean cursive swearing?

Comment: yes I mean cursive swearing

Answer (score 1):

> but there aren't a lot of ways to do that in Mandarin.

That is simply not true. I bet one can write a novel barely with swearing words in Chinese mandarin.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_Chinese_profanity

Please don't use those words，very disgusting. but if you meet those words， you may want to know it， so it is not bad to check it out.

Those are in different levels, some of them are common words that could be used without any negative meanings.